Given $f^\prime(p) = f^{\prime\prime}(p) = 0, f^{\prime\prime\prime}(p)\neq 0$ prove that $p$ is not a local minimum or maximum.
Let $ f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $p\in (a,b)$. Assume that $f$ is $3$ times differentiable at p, with $$f^\prime(p) = f^{\prime\prime}(p) = 0, f^{\prime\prime\prime}\neq 0.$$
Prove that $p$ is not a local minimum or a local maximum point of $f$.
My attempt:
Using Taylor's theorem, $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that:
$$f(x) = f(p) + f^\prime(p)(x-p) + \frac{1}{2!}f^{\prime\prime}(p)(x-p)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(c)(x-c)^3.$$ Thus the expression (using the conditions provided) reduces to:
$$f(x) = f(p) + \frac{1}{6}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(c)(x-c)^3.$$ If we assume that $p$ is a local minimum, then for $p$ sufficiently close (i.e. $\exists \delta$ such that for $x\in(p-\delta, p+\delta), f(p) < f(x)$ and vice-versa if $p$ is a local maximum). However, I cannot see if this line of reasoning will lead to a contradiction. Am I on the right tracks?

Note $f(x)-f(p)$ changes signs around $c$.

I suggest you to consider the following form of Taylor developement: $f(x)=f(p)+\frac16 f'''(p)(x-p)^3+o((x-p)^3)$. This means that $f(x)-f(p)$ is approximately a cubic around $p$...

This is a good idea, but the issue you face, which is a common one, is that one has no apparent control over $c$; it is hard to get a sign-contradiction if, by some fluke, $c>p$ was always possible, and you also do not know much about $f'''(c)$ in the general case where $f'''$ isn't continuous (or perhaps doesn't even exist!) away from $p$.
Instead let's consider the Peano form of the remainder. Here, we get to take back control of the $f'''$ term and express: $f(x)-f(p)=\frac{1}{6}f'''(p)(x-p)^3+\psi(x)$, valid on all $(a,b)$, where $\psi$ is "some" function (easily found by algebra) but the point is that we know $\lim_{x\to p}\psi(x)(x-p)^{-3}=0$. The idea is that if $x>p$ I should get something of one sign and if $p<x$ I should get something of the opposite sign, causing a contradiction.
However, I need to worry about $\psi$... but this is not so bad; contemplate $\epsilon:=\frac{1}{6}|f'''(p)|>0$. I know by the very definition of limit that there is some threshold $\delta>0$ so that on $(p\pm\delta)$ we have $|\psi(x)|<\epsilon|x-p|^3$, and by the triangle inequalities it follows (for $x$ in this interval) that $\mathrm{sgn}\left(\frac{1}{6}f'''(p)(x-p)^3+\psi(x)\right)=\mathrm{sgn}(\frac{1}{6}f'''(p)(x-p)^3)$. Clearly this is just $\mathrm{sgn}(f'''(p)(x-p))$; by taking, say, $x_\pm:=p\pm\frac{1}{2}\delta$ I observe: $$\mathrm{sgn}(f(x_+)-f(p))\neq\mathrm{sgn}(f(x_-)-f(p))$$With both quantities nonzero, so it follows $p$ is neither a local minimum nor a local maximum, since this would work for any $0<\delta’<\delta$; no smaller neighbourhood can work, we will always observe a sign flip.

It is actually much easier. Note that by the second derivative test, $p$ is a local maximum or minimum of $f'$, without loss of generality let's assume minimum. Since $f'(p)=0$ this means that in some neighborhood of $p$ the derivative is always non negative, and so $f$ is increasing in this neighborhood. So if $p$ was a local maximum or minimum of $f$, it would follows that $f$ must be constant at least in some one sided neighborhood of $p$. (why?) But this clearly contradicts the assumption $f'''(p)\ne 0$.
